# How to remove statusbaritem from code?

Tags: macos, cocoa, statusbar

My app have 2 status bar icons. (StatusItem)

First one is always on.
Second one shows up only with one feature.

My problem starts with this code

```
-(void)deleteStatusBarItem
{
    NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    [bar removeStatusItem:statusBarItem];
}
```

It doesn't work if i don't click on my custom status item view.

Here the code i trigger in usual way my menu.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    _isPressed = YES;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(afterDelayCall) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
-(void)afterDelayCall
{
    [[_statusItem menu] setDelegate:(id)self];
    [_statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:[_statusItem menu]];
}
```

Here the code of init. Just in case.

```
-(void)addStatusBarItem
{
    if (!statusBarItem)
    {
        NSStatusBar* bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
        statusBarItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:60];

        trayMenu = [NSMenu new];

        NSMenuItem* startRecordingItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start recording" action:@selector(testfunc) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [startRecordingItem setTarget:self];
        [trayMenu addItem:startRecordingItem];

        NSMenuItem* closeRecordingItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close recorder" action:@selector(hideRecordWindow) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [closeRecordingItem setTarget:self];
        [trayMenu addItem:closeRecordingItem];

        goToFullScreenItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fullscreen mode" action:@selector(fullScreenAction) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [goToFullScreenItem setTarget:self];
        [trayMenu addItem:goToFullScreenItem];

        [statusBarItem setMenu:trayMenu];

        VRICustomStatusBarView* contentView = [VRICustomStatusBarView new];
        contentView.seconds = 0;
        contentView.timeStringToDraw = @"00:00";
        contentView.statusItem = statusBarItem;
        [statusBarItem setView:contentView];
        [contentView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(firstInitHack) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:1];
    }
}
```

I was trying to simulate mouse click or popup menu, but it doesn't help.

```
-(void)firstInitHack
{
    CGKeyCode key_code = 125;  // kVK_DownArrow = 125
    CGEventRef event1, event2;
    event1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, key_code, YES);
    event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, key_code, NO);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event1);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, event2);
    CFRelease(event1);
    CFRelease(event2);

    NSEvent* ev = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:event1];
    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:[_statusItem menu] withEvent:ev forView:self];
    [NSTimer scheduledAnimationTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2f target:self selector:@selector(removeStatusItemAfterDelay) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)removeStatusItemAfterDelay
{
    [[_statusItem menu] cancelTracking];
}
```

Any suggestions, what's going on?)

UPDATE:

Maybe this sample project can help? 
http://monosnap.com/file/RFhixVcSuKaUQQtxN7R0U0k6ij81ez

Answer (score 0):

It's a Mavericks bug. And Apple support give me workaround.

```
- (IBAction)removeStatusItem:(id)sender {

    [statusBarItem setView:nil];
    NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    [bar removeStatusItem:statusBarItem];
    statusBarItem = nil;
}
```

Here some discussion about it : https://devforums.apple.com/message/959387#959387
And here the answer from Apple Support : http://monosnap.com/image/tjNKlyF8bF1Kdl0sfpVkZErdZUgURV